# Função para calcular de forma dinâmica a cor de fundo de uma div

Tags: javascript

Eu estou travado em como aplicar uma solução para um problema, imagina que eu tenho uma lista de -100 a 100 e eu quero aplicar de forma dinâmica uma cor de fundo para esses valores que estão numa div, ai eu pensei em usar rgba, quando o número fosse positivo o tom de verde seria mais forte e se fosse mais negativo seria mais vermelho, como também, quando for se aproximando mais do 0 vai ficando com um tom de amarelo mais intenso, e tem um range para esses valores, no exemplo eu falei de valores de 100 até -100, mas poderia ser outro range, eu realizei diversos cálculos, tentei usar uma paleta de cores do bootstrap 5, mas está bem difícil, um adendo, eu estava usando opacidade para definir o tom das cores, também, defini que o valor mínimo da opacidade seria de 0.5 e o máximo 1, e, estou tentando aplicar isso em VueJS, mas o principal é fazer esse método funcionar.Compartilharei o código para melhor entendimento, essa foi minha tentativa:

```js
function dynamicColor() {

  var red = 0;
  var green = 0;
  var blue = 0;
  var opacity = 0;
  
  var rangeMax = 100;  
  var rangeMin = -100;
  
  var value = 10;
  
  var pctRangeMin = (rangeMin * 10)/100;
  var pctRangeMax = (rangeMax * 10)/100;
  var percentage = (value - rangeMin - pctRangeMin) / (rangeMax - rangeMin) * 100;
  
  console.log('Porcentagem: ' + Math.round(percentage) + '%');
  
  
  if (value >= pctRangeMax) {
    console.log('Cor: Verde');
    green = 255;
    opacity = 0.5 + Math.min((1 + percentage/100) / 2, 0.5);
    opacity = opacity.toFixed(2);
  } else if (value <= pctRangeMin) {
    console.log('Cor: Vermelha');
    red = 255;
    opacity = Math.min((1 + percentage/100) / 2);
  } else {
    green = 255;
    red = 255;
    var intensity = Math.min((Math.abs(percentage) / 10) / 2, 1);
  
    console.log('Cor: Amarelo');
    opacity = (((intensity) / 2) - 1).toFixed(2);
  
    opacity = Math.abs(opacity);
  }
  
  
  return `rgba(${red}, ${green}, ${blue}, ${opacity})`;
  
  }
  
  console.log('Valor da função: ' + dynamicColor());
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Usei uma outra forma para tentar reproduzir uma solução para a sua lógica. Usei uma função que retorna o `hsl()` e altero apenas o `Hue (h)`.

```js
// Função em si
function dynamicColor(value) {
  return `hsl(${(value + 100) * 0.6}, 100%, 45%)`
}

// Código de demosntração
const container = document.getElementById("container")
for (let i = -100; i <= 100; i++) {
  const colorDiv = document.createElement('div')
  colorDiv.classList.add('color')
  colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = dynamicColor(i)
  container.append(colorDiv)
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.color {
  height: 25px;
  width: 2px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Observações:**

1. Caso você queira alterar o range, deve ser feitas algumas modificações, por exemplo, na função tem um `value + 100`, isso acontece pois você tem valores negativos no seu range e para esse cálculo precisamos considerar todos os valores como positivos. Case seu range fosse de -250 a 250, seria necessário por `value + 250` e caso fosse um range de 0 a 100, não seria necessário adicionar nenhum valor ao `value`.
2. Na função também tem outro cálculo que é a multiplicação do valor por **0.6**. Este é um cálculo baseado na quantidade de números disponíveis dentro desse range (que neste caso é 201, eu considerei como 200 mesmo). Esse valor deve ser inversamente proporcional a essa quantidade. Por exemplo, se houvesse apenas 100 números dentro do range, o valor usado na multiplicação deveria ser **1.2**.